# Why savon :attributes! not working with an object called Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, soap, savon

When supplying savon with:

```
hash = { 
              "Objects" => { //stuff here }, 
           :attributes! => { "Objects" => {"xsi:type" => "Something"}}
       }
```

I get:

```
<Objects>...</Objects>
```

When supplying savon with anything else i get the expected result:

```
hash = { 
         "foo" => { //stuff here }, 
         :attributes! => { "foo" => {"xsi:type" => "Something"}}
       }
```

I get:

```
<foo xsi:type="Something"></foo>
```

I must use the string "Objects" as the key. I am coding to a 3rd party SOAP web service. I cannot use a symbol because the first letter would become a lower cap.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You have to change :attributes! to :@xsi:type=>"Something" within the hash where you want the attribute

Like:

```
"foo"=>{:@xsi:type=>'something', //stuff here}
```